# The structure being aggregated has to know the information from the structure that aggregates this structure

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Like in std::pair< int, std::vector > vector has to know it's pair first element (that is int).

I got the following interesting problem. Code is provided, please read the comments.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace DataWorld {
    using DataType = int;

    // It is a data. Holder struct will hold this data. But holder has it's id
    struct Data {
        DataType storage[5];
        void Show() {
            std::cout << "my_holder_index" << " "; // here the data has to know the id of the holder that holds this data
            for(auto elem : storage) {
                std::cout << elem << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

    };
    struct DataHolder {
        Data my_data;
        std::string my_holder_index;
        DataHolder(Data my_data, std::string my_holder_index)
            : my_data(my_data)
            , my_holder_index(my_holder_index) {}
        void Show() {
            // Do not show holder id here! It is the data that has to know it.
            my_data.Show();
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    using namespace DataWorld;

    DataHolder dhs[] = {
        { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, "nat" },
        { {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, "even" },
        { {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, "odd" }
    };

    for(auto dh : dhs) {
        dh.Show();
    }
}
```

- Is possible to solve this task without manual providing  'my_holder_index' variable to Data (like ': my_data(my_data(my_holder_index))').
- Is it possible for a std::vector to find a place in the memory where it's DataHolder struct was instantiated and try to find my_holder_index?
- Is it possible to realise this behavior using c++ / STL without point-memory manipulations? 
  Thanks

Comment: No, no, no, and this sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: What does `std::vector` have to do with anything? You keep talking about it, but your code doesn't use it anywhere.

Comment: What do you need `DataHolder` for? Why can't `Data` hold `my_holder_index` in addition to `storage`?

Comment: "*Like in std::pair< int, std::vector > vector has to know it's pair first element (that is int).*" Um, no. No it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, this sounds weird. But it is clear that all memory addresses are determined at the moment of executing Show function. So it is possible. Igor, the task to avoid the situation you've described.

Comment: @Pleeea: It's still unclear what `vector` has to do with anything you've described. And again, `vector` in a `pair` has no idea that it is in a pair. So no, it does not know the `pair`s first element.

Comment: `the task to avoid the situation you've described` But why is this situation to be avoided? What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? Lack of the explanation for the latter is what makes it an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have yet to explain what anything in your question has to do with `vector` (as well as made the nonsensical claim that a `vector` in a `pair` has access to the other element in the `pair`), I'm going to focus on finding a solution for the actual code you've presented.

Question 2:

> Is it possible for a std::vector to find a place in the memory where it's DataHolder struct was instantiated and try to find my_holder_index?

No. There is no legal way in C++ (ie: without invoking UB) for a member subobject to gain access to a variable declared in its owning object. At least, not without you passing that variable to it.

Oh sure, you could probably cast `this` to an `unsigned char*`, do some pointer arithmetic, and cast it to `std::string`. And that might "work" for some implementations. But it would not be legal C++. If for no other reason than the fact that nothing prevents you from declaring `Data` in a place that *isn't* inside some other object that provides a `std::string` member.

Question 1 & 3:

> Is possible to solve this task without manual providing 'my_holder_index' variable to Data (like ': my_data(my_data(my_holder_index))').
>
> Is it possible to realise this behavior using c++ / STL without point-memory manipulations?

The correct way to do what you're doing is to use the CRTP. `Data` should be a base class subobject of `DataHolder` (or whomever else might want to use it). It would take, as a template parameter, the class that will derive from it. It can therefore `static_cast` `this` to a pointer to the derived class. And so long as you always pass the derived class as the template parameter, you won't provoke undefined behavior:

```
template<typename Derived>
  //Requires that `Derived` have a publicly accessible `my_holder_index` field
  //Which is something that has an `operator<<(ostream)` overload for it.
struct Data {
    DataType storage[5];
    void Show() {
        std::cout << "my_holder_index" << derived().my_holder_index;
        for(auto elem : storage) {
            std::cout << elem << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Derived &derived() {return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);}
    const Derived &derived() const {return static_cast<const Derived&>(*this);}

};
struct DataHolder : Data<DataHolder> {
    std::string my_holder_index;
    DataHolder(std::string my_holder_index)
        : my_holder_index(my_holder_index) {}
    void Show() {
        // Do not show holder id here! It is the data that has to know it.
        Data<DataHolder>::Show();
    }
};
```